# Building a tiny shop website, setting ID for image

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am new to HTML/JSP, i am trying to build a tiny shop online website. I have successfully connected to MySQL Database, in my database there is a table hold all the information about stuff i want to sell (image, price, description etc.) and I created a products.jsp that will show all the image of the stuff i sell, each image will redirect to one jsp page name stuff.jsp. How can I set an ID for each image in order to match with ones in database so that in stuff.jsp will show what stuff that i clicked

I have tried so far:
in my database SQL:

```
    create table products(
ID int not null auto_increment,
product_name varchar (40),
price int,
description varchar (100),
primary key(ID))
```

and in my products.jsp, i created some image link like:

```
  <a href="stuffs.jsp"><img src="images/php.jpg" alt="Image"></a>
<a href="stuffs.jsp">Khi Nguoi Lon Co Don Pham Hong Phuoc</a>
```

Comment: The data base in mysql needs a column in the images table that auto_increment every time  an image is added to it. Thats the way to get the unique id for each image.

Comment: We need to know first what you have tried.

Comment: can you be more specific? I have added the code I have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get the table data to jsp.

`Class.forName("your jdbc driver");` - like jdbc.odbc.jdbcDriver., and get a connection then get the table data, parse the resultset.

```
ResultSet rs = yourStatement.executeQuery();
while(rs.hasNext()) // this is pseudo code only
id = rs.next().getString("ID);
```

Only then, you can use id in your html fields...

```
<a href="stuffs.jsp"><img src="images/php.jpg" alt=" id="<%= image_corresponding_to_this>"Image"></a>
<a href="stuffs.jsp">Khi Nguoi Lon Co Don Pham Hong Phuoc</a>
```

Comment: i still cant solve it, the id seem not to be regconized

Comment: What is the server code you have written ? Did you happen to query the database in jsp ? show the code .. If you did, try displaying all the data with the ids in the final html page. let us see how it is working...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide the data to JSP directly via database without any back end code.
you need to add some backend code as you can use ajax and call e.g. servlet which will call database as per the required data and then you can get that data in from of JSON from that Servlet